# iOS - Performance testing?

Tags: ios, performance, instruments

What is the right instrument tool to perform analyze testing on iOS.
I am noticing some lags on my app while performing certain task, and I would like to see what's causing these performance hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[Time Profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html)** is what you want.
It allows you to check which operations took longest.

It can even distinguish calls you are responsible for and things you don't even affect.